# How to use prolog rules in a java application

Tags: java, prolog

I hope my question is not a duplicate... I have implemented some rules using Prolog. I would like to ask if there is any way to use these rules in a java application. I do not want to implement everything in java from scratch. I would like to embed the code written in Prolog in a java application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @YiannaCo it would be helpful to know what IDE you use for Java? Just in case there are available plugins for it. Although I believe the ones I listed should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways. But judging from your question you're looking for a quick solution.

**JPL (since i notice a lot of people are using SWI nowadays):**

- http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/Java.html

**The GNU Prolog library for Java:**

- http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/

**SICtus (It comes with syntax examples, etc so it shouldn't be hard for you to use it quickly)**

- http://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/3.7.1/html/sicstus_12.html

**tuProlog (Said to be the easiest to use, beginner friendly)**

- http://www.alice.unibo.it/xwiki/bin/view/Tuprolog/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast and dense reply. It is true that I am looking for a fast solution. I do not use any IDE for Java. I prefer to write everything from scratch using only an editor, in particular emacs. I compile my code using Ant or script files.